# Error thrown while decrypting AES encrypted string using NodeJS Crypto

Tags: node.js, encryption, aes, cryptojs

This is my encrypting function:-

```
        const key = '3f29658160528447';
        const cipher = Crypto.createCipheriv('aes-128-ecb', key, null);
        const encryptedQueryParams = Buffer.concat([cipher.update(stringToEncrypt), cipher.final()]).toString('base64');
        return encryptedQueryParams;
```

When I try to decrypt this using the following function:-

```
    const key = '3f29658160528447';
    const cipher = Crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-128-ecb', key, null);
    const decryptedQueryParams = Buffer.concat([cipher.update(encryptedText, 'base64'), cipher.final()]).toString();
    return decryptedQueryParams;
```

I get an error:-
`Error: error:0606506D:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length`

I've gone through quite a few threads, but can't seem to fix this. My Node version is 14.17.1.

Comment: The posted code works: https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/AO7. Look for a typo or it may be an environment specific problem.

Comment: Note that ECB is insecure.

Comment: @Topaco Well in my actual code I'm getting the encrypted text as a request query parameter. This is how I'm handling it:- const encryptedText = req.query.e as string; //e is the query param name. Is typecasting it to string causing the problem?

Comment: Possibly. Since I don't know the type or content of `req.query.e`, I can't answer that reliably.

Comment: @Topaco I'm just passing the encrypted text in req.query.e. req is a variable of type Request. I'm calling the function with an API endpoint like this: http://localhost:3000/v1/test?e=MDDC8XHHPIC1TAlMCN0A22HpIf86v3/Xj0co4U2KszFUrqWewI9iSdkrW1zVxSCl

Comment: This does not answer my question about the data. Why don't you check if `req.query.e` contains the data from `encryptedQueryParams`? If both are different, you need to determine where the data is changed between encryption and decryption.

Comment: @Topaco Found the problem. The string I was encoding resulted in a base-64 encoded string which contained the '+' sign. And I was passing this string in the query parameter. Hence '+' was treated as space. Solved the problem by replacing characters after encoding and before decoding.

Comment: Or apply `base64url` instead of `base64`.